# is orientdb dead (in terms of php language binding)

Tags: php, neo4j, orientdb, graph-databases

In terms of graphdb, I have been living under the rock for last few years, though I had a chance to explore orientdb as a candidate for an app few years back.

Now I am in a need of a graphdb for a typical friend of friend of friend type data. Naturally orientdb was my first thought because I already had tinkered with it in the past. But when I checked its php driver at [github](https://github.com/Ostico/PhpOrient), it seems like it is an abandoned project.

Looking up into [neo4j-php-client](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-php-client) also gave a similar impression of a dated or dying project. I am wondering if I am arriving at the graphdb party when it is already over? Has the world moved on to something newer and better than graphdb for such data as friend of friend of friend? Or is php simply not a language of interest anymore for such tools? I am sure regular users of graphdb tools can point me to the right tool to use in 2018 when I can not switch the php to another language.

Comment: Hi Waku-2. Yes the orientdb php driver seems a little old without any commit for the last 2 years. So personally I will not use it ... The other part of your question (about Neo4j) your question is too opened.

Comment: Can't speak for OrientDB, however Neo4j is thriving. As for the PHP community driver  as far as I know, still very much supported (author can confirm). Lacks commits because it is stable. However, this question is best moved to StackExchange. StackOverflow is for specific technical problems, backed by evidence of what was tried, and a clear problem statement of what needs to be solved.

Comment: Thanks Jasper, I can move the question to StackExchange but I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

2,

I had the same question one month ago and I have decided to use REST-API. It works, of course, also with php. It is much stable and I made the good experience with it ([OrientDB-REST](https://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/misc/OrientDB-REST.html)). Also, the php-driver was updated two weeks ago with [native support](https://github.com/Ostico/PhpOrient/releases/tag/v1.3.0) of OrientDB 3.0.x